# How to get input text value from inside td

Tags: jquery

```
<tr>
 <td>
      <input type="text" name="desc[]">
 </td>
 <td>
      <input type="text" name="duration[]">
 </td>
 <td>
      <input type="text" name="start[]" class="start">
 </td>
 <td>
       <input type="text" name="wait[]">
 </td>
 <td>
       <input type="text" name="end[]">
 </td>
 <td>
      <input type="text" name="phone[]">
 </td>
</tr>
```

I have such multiple rows. I need to fetch the values off all tds on keyup event on the td with input name start(and i also need to avoid values of desc[] and phone[]). Since they are many i cannot go with ids, need help in parent child approach with jquery.

I was able to reach parent tr on keyup event on the above mentioned td but not able to access values of input field in other tds. the jquery code i used

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".start").keyup(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().get(-3).tagName);
    })
});
```

Comment: I think you should describe your problem better. `td` s by default don't have values. Do you mean that you want to get all values of input elements named `start[]` if there is a keyup event in any of those?

Comment: if there is a keyup event on row 1(as i mentioned in my question a i have multiple row like this), i need to have values of all inputs in that particular row.

Comment: commenting to each given responce, can help us to figure out what you are looking for!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ah I think a understand now. Have a look if this really is what you want:

```
$(".start").keyup(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find("input").each(function() {
        alert(this.value)
    });
});
```

This will give you all input values of a row.

**Update:**
To get the value of **not** all elements you can use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("input:not([name^=desc][name^=phone])").each(function() {
     alert(this.value)
});
```

Actually I am not 100% sure whether it works this way, maybe you have to use two `not`s instead of this one combining both conditions.

Comment: @Ashish Rajan: You can extend it like this: `.find("input:not([name^=desc][name^=phone])")` using the `:not()` selector. http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help.

```
var inputVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(x) input").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var values = {};
$('td input').each(function(){
  values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
}
```

Haven't tested, but that should do it...

Comment: This would get the values of the final row, not the current row

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly you're looking for here, so hope I'm not way off base.

I'm assuming what you mean is that when a keyup event occurs on the input with class "start" you want to get the values of all the inputs in neighbouring <td>s:

```
    $('.start').keyup(function() {
        var otherInputs = $(this).parents('td').siblings().find('input');

        for(var i = 0; i < otherInputs.length; i++) {
            alert($(otherInputs[i]).val());
        }
        return false;
    });
```